# ASIHTTPRequest file upload / blank responseString

Tags: iphone, sdk, asihttprequest

I'm using the ASIHTTPRequest wrapper and I'm able to upload files successfully. However, `[request responseString]` always returns blank!

The documentation says to use `[request responseString]` when fetching text data, but I've seen many code examples using `[request responseString]` when uploading files. Does this work when uploading files? Is `[request responseString]` supposed to return the echo string in the server's php script or what?

If the server's upload php scripts ends with:

```
echo "success";
```

or

```
echo "failure";
```

Can ASIHTTPRequest read this string? How can the server send a message back to ASIHTTPRequest?

Thank you.

Comment: the responseString (success/failure) should be available when the request has finished, where do you call [request responseString] ?